# Is there a C preprocessor which can replace contiguous else and ifdef directives?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a piece of code which looks like this,

```
#ifdef A
  printf("A");
#else
  #ifdef B
    printf("B");
  #endif
#endif
```

`else` and `ifedef B` can be replaced with `elif defined B` as per [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html#Defined).
But, isn't there `elifdef` directive in C language?

---

NOTE: `elif B` is not suitable for this, it needs an expression; where as `A`, `B` are compile time switches with no value defined for them.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: what's wrong with `elif defined`?

Comment: Too late to add that now. That ship sailed in the 1970s.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: @DYZ, no problems while running the code, as things are 'pre' processed.
Just a less code writing stuff

Comment: @tadman, :D. But, apart from C standards, any compiler extensions?

Comment: Not really. This is a lost cause. Just accept it for what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The directives are `#elifdef` and `#elifndef`, starting from C23. They are implemented in [GCC 12](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-12/changes.html), seem to be already implemented in Clang 13 according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/23), were proposed in [N2645](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2645.pdf) and it are also part of the working draft [N3096](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) in section **6.10.1 Conditional inclusion**.

> The conditional expression inclusion preprocessing directives, #ifdef, #ifndef, #elifdef, and #elifndef directives are collectively known as the conditional inclusion preprocessing directives.

```c
#ifdef A
  printf("A");
#elifdef B
  printf("B");
#endif
```